# Show new data from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, gmail

I was wondering, how gmail's and facebook's new information view works. Like in gmail.. empty inbox and without page reload show the new mile. It works like jquery update or is there some jquery, php code ho check the database.

Comment: You can use AJAX to get entire pages without reload, [more info](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: It's probably doing an AJAX request for new mail/messages and then updating to show that.

Answer (score 1):

The process is a combination of backend server processing (like PHP, which just waits for a request and provides the update results), plus front end with javascript (or jQuery as you describe, which requests the update, or waits for a notification that there IS an update).

This process above is a combo of both, can't be done alone, and there are many guides available for AJAX functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use signalR to listen and when new data is sent it will send it to the listening connections.

Microsoft is pushing it but it's really just a javascript (AJAX) framework so it could be used with any platform.

[MSDN Announcment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/announcing-the-release-of-signalr-0-5-3.aspx)

[SignalR on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signalr)